# How do I avoid "Not Secure" messages when developing locally with IIS and personal certificates?

Tags: asp.net, ssl, iis

I'm developing with ASP.NET and find it annoying that I constantly get "Not Secure" messages when accessing my local website through IIS just because I have a personal self-signed certificate.

Is there a way to avoid this without going through what appears to be a very complicated process of setting up my own certificate server - I am just running on my local IIS however note the site I'm developing does not use localhost, but a specific website configured on my local IIS.

Answer (score 0):

basically while creating a certificate you need to raise it with your localhost domain(i.e. Hostname that you pass in the Binding of the application). If yes then you wont be getting the Error any more. Or else for your local setup you can change the binding to Http.